# Загрузка изображений на сайте

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, media-queries

При использовании media-запросов в CSS будет ли загружаться `background` для десктопа, если разрешение соответствует мобильному устройству?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас есть медиа-запрос для мобильных устройств, то картинка не будет загружаться для десктопа, если вы загрузили сайт на телефоне или в маленьком окне браузере. То же самое работает в обратную сторону.

### Пример

```css
div {
  height: 512px;
  width: 512px;
  background-image: url("http://pngimg.com/uploads/facebook_logos/facebook_logos_PNG19753.png");
}

@media screen and (min-width: 240px) and (max-width:830px) {
  div {
    background-image: url("http://download.seaicons.com/icons/limav/flat-gradient-social/128/Facebook-icon.png");
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Можете убедиться в этом сами во вкладке браузера `netwrok`, если будите открывать страничку на разных разрешениях.

### Результат загрузки при маленьком разрешении

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как видно из скриншота, для маленького разрешения загрузился соответствующий `background` и никакой другой.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, в этом медиа запросе говорится что на разрешении от 500рх и выше будет картинка `1.jpg`

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  background-image: url("../img/1.jpg");
}
```

а в этом, что от 1000рх уже будет `2.jpg`, следовательно `1.jpg` уже выводиться не будет

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  background-image: url("../img/2.jpg");
}
```